# Down the lane meaning

Tags: grammar, american-english

Can somebody kindly explain the meaning of sentence? - She rides her bicycle every evening down the lane

Comment: Could it refer to "memory lane"?

Comment: If meant literally, it would simply mean "along the (small) road", and if the road slopes, they would be riding the bicycle downhill. If you think this isn't the correct reading, you'll need to expand your question to explain why.

Comment: It should be added that there are several figurative meanings to "up/down the lane/road".  But the above use does not appear to be figurative.

Answer (score 2):

From the unfairly downvoted answer by Carrie Villalobos:

> A lane is a small road. So, it would be similar to saying she rides
>   her bike every evening down the road.
>
> Up and down can mean a difference in height, or it can mean closer to
>   or farther from a point. In this case "down the lane" might mean that
>   as she is riding it is farther away from her starting point. If you
>   say one direction is "down", then if she goes in the opposite
>   direction you would then say she is coming "up" the road.

I'll add that "up" and "down" can sometimes refer to motion relative to a given destination.  Eg, "up the road" may be towards town.  But such meanings are local conventions.

Comment: So, I assumed this. Suppose a road has 6 lanes. Let's say the road rules are walk/drive in left direction. I am in India. So extremely left lane means down the road. Extremely right means up the road. Please confirm my understanding.

Comment: @Pankaj - No, "up" and "down" are relative to some geographic feature.  Maybe a hill, maybe a town, maybe just the person's residence.